# Custom bidirectional bindings in JavaFX

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx, javabeans

I'm trying to implements a GUI involving a computation of 2 fields. My model has 2 properties and one binding.

```
ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> price = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
ObjectProperty<BigDecimal> quantity= new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
ObjectBinding<BigDecimal> totalPrice = new ObjectBinding<BigDecimal>() {
    { bind(price,quantity);}
    protected BigDecimal computeValue() {
        if (price.get() == null || quantity.get() == null) return null;
        return price.get().multiply(quantity.get());
    }
};
```

My GUI has 3 `TextField` to match price, amount, totalPrice. Usualy, I'm doing a regular binding between my properties and my `TextField` as such

```
priceTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(myModel.priceProperty(), new NumberStringConverter());
```

Now this where it gets a bit tricky. If the user modify the price or the quantity, it has toupdate the TotalPrice (which is what the binding does so far). But I want to be able to do the following: if the user update the TotalPrice, then it recomputes the quantity accordingly to the fixed price.

So the question is: how do I create such a flow => TotalPrice is bind on price and quantity, but quantity is bind on TotalPrice and price. When I input something in the `totalPriceTextfield` it should update the `quantityTextField` and vice versa.

Thanks.

****** Edit ********
Here is an ugly piece of code just to illustrate what I want to achieve (nb: i know i could use `Binding.multiply` and other method but I need for future project to implement the compute function)

```
public class TestOnBindings {

    private DoubleProperty price = new SimpleDoubleProperty(10.0);
    private DoubleProperty quantity = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);
    private DoubleProperty total = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);

    private DoubleBinding totalBinding = new DoubleBinding() {
        {bind(quantity,price);}
        @Override
        protected double computeValue() {
            return quantity.get()*price.get();
        }
    };

    private DoubleBinding quantityBinding = new DoubleBinding() {
        {bind(total,price);}
        @Override
        protected double computeValue() {
            return total.get()/price.get();
        }
    }; 


    public TestOnBindings(){
        total.bind(totalBinding); //should really not do that, looks ugly
        quantity.bind(quantityBinding); //now you're asking for troubles
    }


    public void setPrice(Double price){
        this.price.set(price);
    }


    public void setQuantity(Double quantity){
        this.quantity.set(quantity);
    }

    public void setTotal(Double total){
        this.total.set(total);
    }


    public Double getTotal(){
        return total.get();
    }


    public Double getQuantity(){
        return quantity.get();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestOnBindings test = new TestOnBindings();
        test.setQuantity(5.0);

        System.out.println("Total amount = " + test.getTotal());
    }

}
```

and the obvious nice error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: A bound value cannot be set.
    at javafx.beans.property.DoublePropertyBase.set(DoublePropertyBase.java:142)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that my question has already been answered in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703544/bidirectional-binding-with-objectbinding-in-javafx?rq=1) and that this guy provided a simple way on his [blog](http://wittcarl.deneb.uberspace.de/wordpress/customized-bidirectional-bindings-in-javafx/)

I modified a bit his class to adapt my needs and have a very easy to use class:

```
public class CustomBinding {

    public static <A ,B> void bindBidirectional(Property<A> propertyA, Property<B> propertyB, Function<A,B> updateB, Function<B,A> updateA){
        addFlaggedChangeListener(propertyA, propertyB, updateB);
        addFlaggedChangeListener(propertyB, propertyA, updateA);
    }

    public static <A ,B> void bind(Property<A> propertyA, Property<B> propertyB, Function<A,B> updateB){
        addFlaggedChangeListener(propertyA, propertyB, updateB);
    }

    private static <X,Y> void addFlaggedChangeListener(ObservableValue<X> propertyX, WritableValue<Y> propertyY, Function<X,Y> updateY){
        propertyX.addListener(new ChangeListener<X>() {
            private boolean alreadyCalled = false;

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends X> observable, X oldValue, X newValue) {
                if(alreadyCalled) return;
                try {
                    alreadyCalled = true;
                    propertyY.setValue(updateY.apply(newValue));
                }
                finally {alreadyCalled = false; }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and then applying it to my example.... Still need a little bit of fine tuning, but it does the job.

```
public class TestOnBindings {

    private DoubleProperty price = new SimpleDoubleProperty(10.0);
    private DoubleProperty quantity = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);
    private DoubleProperty total = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);

    public TestOnBindings(){
        CustomBinding.<Number,Number>bindBidirectional(quantity, total, 
                (newQuantity)-> newQuantity.doubleValue() * price.get(),
                (newTotal)-> newTotal.doubleValue() /price.get());

        CustomBinding.<Number,Number>bind(price, total, 
                (newPrice)-> newPrice.doubleValue() * quantity.get());
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price){this.price.set(price);}
    public void setQuantity(Double quantity){this.quantity.set(quantity);}
    public void setTotal(Double total){this.total.set(total);}

    public Double getTotal(){return total.get();}
    public Double getQuantity(){return quantity.get();}
    public Double getPrice(){return price.get();}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestOnBindings test = new TestOnBindings();

        test.setQuantity(5.0);

        System.out.println("Quantity = " + test.getQuantity());
        System.out.println("Price = " + test.getPrice());
        System.out.println("Total = " + test.getTotal());

        test.setTotal(60.0);

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Quantity = " + test.getQuantity());
        System.out.println("Price = " + test.getPrice());
        System.out.println("Total = " + test.getTotal());

        test.setPrice(5.0);

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Quantity = " + test.getQuantity());
        System.out.println("Price = " + test.getPrice());
        System.out.println("Total = " + test.getTotal());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really have to use bindings?  This will do the job.  Bindings are just fancy listeners anyway.

```
public TestOnBindings(){
    price.addListener((obs,ov,nv) -> {
        total.set(price.doubleValue()*quantity.doubleValue());
    });
    //could be same listener as price if total is a complicated function
    quantity.addListener((obs,ov,nv) -> {
        total.set(price.doubleValue()*quantity.doubleValue());
    });
    total.addListener((obs,ov,nv) -> {
        quantity.set(total.doubleValue()/price.doubleValue());
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian, yes you're right and thanks for your comment. The only thing is you want to avoid ending in endless loops of refresh.

Comment: I thought about that, but it didn't happen when I tested it.  If it's a problem you can write non-anonymous listeners and in the one that sets total just do `total.removeListener(...);` and re add it after.

Comment: TestOnBindings test = new TestOnBindings();
test.setQuantity(5.0);
System.out.println("Total amount = " + test.getTotal());
test.setTotal(60.0);
System.out.println("Quantity amount = " + test.getQuantity());

Am ending up with the output 100/6/60 (for initial value of 10 for price, 1 for quantity and 1 for total) which suggest me that there is a loop. Thanks for all your suggestion.

Comment: I just tested for errors and infinite loops, I didn't check the math.  It works now, just a silly math error.  I had qty = tot / qty .  I can't find the reference but there is a mechanism to stop listeners from looping.

Comment: True, your code does not cause an infinite loop. But when working on a GUI, the following code does result in a StackOverflowError, because of the aforementioned infinite loop problem.

`slider1.valueProperty().addListener((obs,nv,ov)->{slider2.setValue(nv.doubleValue());});
slider2.valueProperty().addListener((obs,nv,ov)->{slider1.setValue(nv.doubleValue());});`