# Shouldn't this be an infinite loop of properties updating?

Tags: java, javafx

Shouldn't this be an infinite loop of properties updating? Why does that update only once?

```
Property<Node> nodeProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
Property<HBox> hBoxProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
nodeProperty.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    hBoxProperty.setValue((HBox) newValue);
});
hBoxProperty.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    nodeProperty.setValue(newValue);
});
nodeProperty.setValue(new HBox());
```

Comment: most likely because the listener is only invoked if the value changes, not whenever `setValue` is called.

Comment: the change propagation mechanism checks if the new value equals the old before firing (partly in ObjectPropertyBase and partly in EventListenerHelper - if I remember correctly) BTW: it's instructive to read the source code :)

Comment: @kleopatra so basically the checking mechanism used here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27053995/15368273 is useless? I'm talking about the `if (alreadyCalled)` part

Comment: probably (too lazy to look at such an old question, thingies tend to change ;), but it's built-in

Comment: Not useless. You don't necessarily know how the observable is going to behave, as it has some flexibility in how it determines if the value has changed. For instance, [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.base/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html) claims the built-in implementations use reference equality instead of object equality. If your code caused different-but-equal objects to be set then you'd get an infinite loop; a boolean flag would help prevent that.