# Bind two Spinner controls into a TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, spinner, tableview, javafx-8

How to bind two Spinner controls into a TableView ? According to the sreenshot below, I would like to do something : colA = colB / 2 (*and colB = colA x 2...*) :

[image: exemple screenshot]

Here the snippet (deliberately simple) used to expose the problem :

### TestApp.java

```
public class TestApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        final TableView<MyBean> tableView = new TableView<>();
        final TableColumn<MyBean, Integer> colA = new TableColumn<>("Col A");
        final TableColumn<MyBean, Integer> colB = new TableColumn<>("Col B");

        colA.setCellFactory(col -> new SpinnerCell<MyBean, Integer>());
        colA.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyBean, Integer>("valA"));

        colB.setCellFactory(col -> new SpinnerCell<MyBean, Integer>());
        colB.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<MyBean, Integer>("valB"));

        tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        tableView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new MyBean(1, 2)));
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(colA, colB);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(tableView), 500, 300));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }
}
```

### SpinnerCell.java

```
public class SpinnerCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    private Spinner<Integer> spinner;
    private ObservableValue<T> ov;

    public SpinnerCell() {
        this.spinner = new Spinner<Integer>(0, 100, 1);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(this.spinner);

            if(this.ov instanceof IntegerProperty) {
                this.spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty().unbindBidirectional(((IntegerProperty) this.ov).asObject());
            }

            this.ov = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());

            if(this.ov instanceof IntegerProperty) {
                this.spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bindBidirectional(((IntegerProperty) this.ov).asObject());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### MyBean.java

```
public class MyBean {

    private IntegerProperty valA, valB;

    public MyBean(int valA, int valB) {
        this.valA = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "valA", valA);
        this.valB = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "valB", valB);
    }

    public IntegerProperty valAProperty() {
        return this.valA;
    }

    public void setValA(int valA) {
        this.valA.set(valA);
    }

    public int getValA() {
        return valA.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty valBProperty() {
        return this.valB;
    }

    public void setValB(int valB) {
        this.valB.set(valB);
    }

    public int getValB() {
        return valB.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of using the [extended bidirectional binding support](http://wittcarl.deneb.uberspace.de/wordpress/customized-bidirectional-bindings-in-javafx/) in MyBean:

```
public static class MyBean {

    private IntegerProperty valA; 
    private IntegerProperty valB;

    public MyBean(int valA) {
        this.valA = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "valA", valA);
        this.valB = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "valB", 0);
        updateB(this.valA, null, this.valA.get());
        BidirectionalBinding.<Number, Number>bindBidirectional(
                this.valA, this.valB, this::updateB, this::updateA);
    }

    protected void updateB(ObservableValue<? extends Number> source,  Number old, Number value) {
        setValB(value.intValue() * 2);
    }

    protected void updateA(ObservableValue<? extends Number> source, Number old, Number value) {
        setValA(value.intValue() / 2);
    }

    ... // same as in OP's code
}
```

Plus in the SpinnerCell, bind to the bean property directly (vs. to its asObject wrapper) - there's a typing issue that I don't understand entirely [**update, see below**] (me and generics will never become friends ;-) which stands in the way of successful bidi-binding:

```
public static class SpinnerCell<S, T extends Number> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    private Spinner<T> spinner;
    private ObservableValue<T> ov;

    public SpinnerCell() {
        this(1);
    }    

    public SpinnerCell(int step) {
        this.spinner = new Spinner<>(0, 100, step);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(this.spinner);

            if(this.ov instanceof Property) {
                this.spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty().unbindBidirectional(((Property) this.ov));
            }

            this.ov = getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue(getIndex());

            if(this.ov instanceof Property) {
                this.spinner.getValueFactory().valueProperty().bindBidirectional(((Property) this.ov));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update** (in understanding the problem with .asObject)

The problem is not the typing as such, but (struck again!) the weak listener registration in bidi-binding:

```
// spinner type
Spinner<Integer> spinner;
// value type (in valueFactory):
ObjectProperty<Integer> valueProperty;
// value type in bean:
IntegerProperty valXProperty;
// to be bindeable to spinner's value, needs to be wrapped
// into ObjectProperty<Integer>
// intuitively ... WRONG!
valueProperty.bindBidirectional(bean.valXProperty().asObject());
```

The wrapper created on the fly is a local reference which can (and is) garbage collected as soon as containing method is left ... As always with these weak listening contexts, none (? at least none that I'm aware of) of the alternatives is satisfying:

- relax on typing of the Spinner: using Number (vs.Integer) doesn't require the wrapper because `InterProperty instanceOf ObjectProperty<Number>`
- keep a strong reference to the wrapper somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
valA.bind(valB.divide(2));
```

Comment: Good idea ! But it does not works... The first error is ``Bidirectional binding failed, setting to the previous value`` caused by ``MyBean.valA : A bound value cannot be set.``

Comment: @TibUs what you want is a bidi-binding with an expression in between, right? If so, I would be interested in an answer as well, failed miserable in figure it out ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra yes it's exactly what I want ! I also find [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20704938/2947370) which seems to be a start of solution...

Comment: @TibUs thanks for the link - the binding in the blog http://wittcarl.deneb.uberspace.de/wordpress/customized-bidirectional-bindings-in-javafx/ referenced in the comment it's really working (modulo the usual weirdness with Property<Integer> vs. IntegerProperty)